# How to "hook" on zoom-bounce animation of UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, sprite-kit, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am implementing a `UIScrollView`-like behaviour in a `SpriteKit` scene.

Hooking on `UIScrollView`'s `scrollViewDidScroll(: UIScrollView)` and `scrollViewDidZoom(: UIScrollView)` is pretty straightforward and allows me to have practically the same feel when user is scrolling and zooming.  Bouncing off the scroll boundaries is also practically the same.

The only thing that is "missing" is the animation of a zoom-bounce.  If I zoom-in too much, so that the scale is lower than minimum, then after I release the touch, the original `UIScrollView` functionality would *animate* zooming-out up to allowed minimum, while my simulation snaps back in an instant.

Is there a way to "follow" `UIScrollView`'s animation of zoom-bounce?

Comment: I have run into the same issue you're describing here. Did you ever come up with a workaround?